# Strange result on Double from activity to activity

Tags: android, double, parcelable

I'm trying to pass an Arralyist of some Object with a Double parameter from one activity to another, but after sending it, the Double result is not the same.
My Object Producto implements parcelable

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Producto implements Parcelable {
private String nombre, descripcion, url, tipo;
private Double precio;
private int cantidad;

public Producto(String nombre, String descripcion, Double precio, String url,  String tipo){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.url = url;
}

protected Producto(Parcel in){
    nombre = in.readString();
    descripcion = in.readString();
    url = in.readString();
    tipo = in.readString();
    precio = in.readDouble();
    cantidad = in.readInt();
}

public static final Creator<Producto> CREATOR = new Creator<Producto>() {
    @Override
    public Producto createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Producto(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Producto[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Producto[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(nombre);
    dest.writeString(descripcion);
    dest.writeString(url);
    dest.writeString(tipo);
    dest.writeInt(cantidad);
    dest.writeDouble(precio);
}

public static Creator<Producto> getCreator(){
    return CREATOR;
}
```

}

I'm trying to send it to the next activity inside an arraylist of products.
First Activity

```
                        for (DocumentSnapshot doc: listadoProductos
                             ) {
                                p = new Producto(doc.getString("Nombre"), doc.getString("Descripcion"),
                                        doc.getDouble("Precio"), doc.getString("url2"), doc.getString("Tipo"));
                                nombres.add(p);
                        }
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Productos.class);
                        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("nombres",nombres);
startActivity(intent);
```

And I've checked that at this moment, the values for Precio are ok, in my case 8.92

But when I received the arraylist in the new Activity, the values are not the same

Second Activity

```
ArrayList<Producto> listadoProductos = new ArrayList<>()
Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("nombres")!= null) {
            listadoProductos = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("nombres");
```

Here, the new value is 9.458744551493758E-13
Anyone could explain what's going on and how to get the real value of 8.92?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working with parcelable you must have the correct order in place.

When reading your fields you must have the same order as you was writing them. Here you have:

```java
// writing: first cantidad then precio
dest.writeInt(cantidad);
dest.writeDouble(precio);

// reading is reversed.
precio = in.readDouble();
cantidad = in.readInt();
```

just change the order

```java
cantidad = in.readInt();
precio = in.readDouble();
```

And it should work